# Replacing spaces with hyphens

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the string `"How are you"`. This string should become `"How-are-you"`. 
It's possible with regex? How?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the simple replace space with '-'.

Comment: What do you want `"Two  spaces"` to become?  `"Two--spaces"` or `"Two-spaces"`?  What about `"space and\ttab"`?  `"space-and-tab"` or `"space-and\ttab"`?

Answer (score 7):

Another option is [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
$ python -m timeit 'a="How are you"; a.replace(" ", "-")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.335 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'a="How are you"; "-".join(a.split())'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.589 usec per loop
```

Comment: Yeah but aweis beat you to that answer by 13 minutes as well as Bryan by 2 minutes.  split() has some advantages over replace(), e.g. if there might be more than one space or even tabs between the words.

Answer (score 5):

Just use pythons built in replace method:

```
strs = "How are you"
new_str = strs.replace(" ","-")
print new_str // "How-are-you"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regex?

```
x =  "How are you"
print "-".join(x.split())

--output:--
How-are-you
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your precise needs, there is many variation on that theme *using regular expressions*:

```
# To replace *the* space character only
>>> re.sub(' ', '-', "How are you");

# To replace any "blank" character (space, tab, ...):
>>> re.sub('\s', '-', "How are you");

# To replace any sequence of 1 or more "blank" character (space, tab, ...) by one hyphen:
>>> re.sub('\s+', '-', "How     are             you");

# To replace any sequence of 1 or more "space" by one hyphen:
>>> re.sub(' +', '-', "How     are             you");
```

Please note for "simple" substitution [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) is probably more appropriate than using regular expression (those are *really* powerful, but requires a compilation phase before processing that could be expensive. Not sure this would really impact your program for such a simple case though... ;). Finally for the one special case or replacing *sequences of spaces*, nothing could probably beat `x.join(str.split())`...

Answer (score 2):

As you asked, using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "How are you"
>>> print re.sub('\s', '-', s)
How-are-you
```